# string to pandas function conversion

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have pandas series and I can get mean value as given below.

```
    >>> s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5))
    >>> s
    0   -0.426981
    1    1.322446
    2   -1.505474
    3    0.411286
    4    0.431440
    dtype: float64
    >>> s.mean()
    0.046543382190213201
    >>> s.max()
    1.3224457683044697
```

But I have to  select  operation/function based  keys given in dict below.

```
 >>> pfync = {'average': 'mean()', 'maximin': 'max()', 'minimum': 'min()', 'Standard deviation': 'std()'}
    >>> opType=pfync['average']
    >>> opType
    'mean()'
    >>>
```

How can i get mean/max etc value of series based on variable opType. I want to avoid many if else in my program . Please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you alter your dictionary just a bit, you can use `pd.Series.agg`

```
pfync = {
    'average': 'mean',
    'maximin': 'max',
    'minimum': 'min',
    'Standard deviation': 'std'
}

s.agg(pfync['average'])

0.046543382190213201
```

If you can't alter you dictionary, simply strip off the parentheses.

```
s.agg(pfync['average'].strip('()'))

0.046543382190213201
```

---

For older versions of pandas prior to `0.20`, you can use `__getattr__`

```
s.__getattr__(pfync['average'])()
```

Comment: After changing dict . I get this error AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'agg'. pd version = 0.19.2

Answer (score 0):

You could also use eval to get the values you are looking for. Not sure what the use case is exactly, so I'm printing out the values.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pfync = {
    'average': 'mean()',
    'maximin': 'max()',
    'minimum': 'min()',
    'Standard deviation': 'std()'
}

s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5))

for k, v in pfync.iteritems():
    print v
    print eval('s.'+v), '\n'
```